Heads Up! Could not open project!
I am a competititor of WRO (World Robot Olympiad) and I am using an EV3. I was programming yesterday and today when I opened it, it was unable to open and said: Heads Up! Could not open project!. I also found that there was another article, but I didn't understand it, and also this one was closed, so I just wanted help for my competition and I really want it back, thanks, Alex
